# Add an indication that a post has been edited in the 5 minutes grace period

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, grace-period

Although I think it's ok it doesn't count as an edit, sometimes I leave a comment or an answer to a post, just to come back later and find it has been edited, making me look like I'm crazy for referencing something that does not exist or has changed meaning, without any trace that before it said something else.

I suggest adding some visual indicator that the post has been edited, kind of like editing a comment works now, without it actually counting as an edit for automatic CW conversion purposes.

Comment: There are occasions when this would be nice. OTOH, it'd be one more bit of clutter in the UI, and one more thing to explain to new, confused users.

Comment: @Shog9: huh? If you edit the question within the grace period and it doesn't show up as an edit, **that (the current system) is confusing**. Having edits always show as edits will be **much less confusing** to new users.

Comment: @Koper: the suggestion is for two separate edit indicators. Tell me that's not confusing...

Comment: This has *partly* been implemented in March 2015: [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876).

Comment: How about an __edit pencil__ ==>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something subtle would be nice, maybe change the sentence above the name to

> asked & edited **1 min ago**

or throw the pencil icon in next to the `asked` statement.

Comment: Yes, any one of those things would be ok by me

Comment: Perhaps the pencil would be better, as the asked and edited times differ

Comment: Alternatively, show the pencil in the revision history only? That way, it can be added (or not) *for each revision* as well.

Comment: @Arjan: +1, that's nice and unobtrusive.

Answer (score 10):

Why not have a revision history? I want to look at how it was before sometimes.

Just don't make it bump the question and don't make it count for automatic CW conversion, but for everything else it should just be what it is - an edit.

Comment: I edited it and removed the revision history bit, so your answer is obsolete ;)

Comment: @Downvoter: It is not because I proposed something different. I want edits in the grace period to be **exactly the same as normal edits** (same UI, revision history, etc). The only invisible differences are that they don't bump the question and they don't count towards the CW limit.

Comment: No no, you misunderstood me, I was illustrating my point, I agreed with you, edited my question, and now your answer is addressing something that's missing from the history

Comment: Ah, too bad the above [was declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40257/change-the-way-edits-in-the-grace-period-work).

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I am reading wrong, but [it *seems* all edits in the 5 minute grace period are actually stored separately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88571/responses-list-duplicate-contents-even-though-there-is-only-one-revision/88597#88597). If true, then not-bumping and not-CW-ing is already in place as it is?

Answer (score 7):

Tracking this would be irritating and noisy. If you happen to be *looking at the post* when it is edited, you'll get a real-time indication of the edit; otherwise, the grace period [serves its purpose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285709/why-do-we-have-an-edit-grace-period/285714#285714).

That said, making folks look foolish was never the goal... So, as of now, creating an answer or comment ends the grace period for the last edit on the post. For details, see: [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876)