# Allow to Change Vote When Question Has Been Edited Inside 5 Minute Window

Tags: feature-request, voting, grace-period

Reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649631/c-how-to-convert-display-a-floating-point-exponential-result-into-a-full-whole).

I downvoted the answer by JustABitOfCode within the first few minutes because it was wrong. He made an edit inside the 5 minute window which corrected the mistake he had in his answer. However, I cannot change my downvote to an upvote because the system says the question had to been edited - which it was. I know the 5 minute window was established long time ago for that 5 minute oops period. Is there a way that we can still alter our upvotes somehow but keep the system the same. Meaning, allowing the 5 minute edit grace period and not showing the answer as edited but allowing others to alter their votes if it was edited at all?

Comment: Related, but though `[status-completed]` not a solution I guess: [Why can't I change my vote if the post has been edited during the initial 5mn grace period?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gra/38759#38759) And kind of also related: [Add an indication that a post has been edited in the 5 minutes grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39635/add-an-indication-that-a-post-has-been-edited-in-the-5-minutes-grace-period) which maybe could be based on the same thing.