# Responses list duplicate contents even though there is only one revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, responses

Revision list show only one revision for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users) question.

[image]

But responses list in my profile says there is two with duplicate contents.

[image]

That could be a bug in responses list page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These aren't the droids you're looking for....

It was a non-distinct bug in how we fetch revisions overall, which should have excluded 5 minute edits.  This is now the case, only the latest edit/comment from a 5 minute window will be shown (as it already is everywhere else).

Comment: Interesting! Does this imply that you're actually storing *all* revisions, even when changed within the 5 minute grace period? (That would make implementing [Add an indication that a post has been edited in the 5 minutes grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39635/add-an-indication-that-a-post-has-been-edited-in-the-5-minutes-grace-period) quite easy...‽)

Comment: @Arjan - Kind of, and only in some cases...a *stub* is stored, and the way it's aggregated from the database makes it not so simple without a big performance shift.

Comment: Too bad, @Nick ;-) What about only retrieving *the number* of stubs then? Just like with comments: *this revision was edited 2 times*?