# How should I respond when my answer is ignored?

Tags: discussion, answers

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8661020/814761) question earlier today.

Although it doesn't show it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8661052/revisions), Josh Smith's initial post was simply to use `$("html")` to select the HTML element.

I answered the question a minute later with the way to select the HTML element given that the class of the body element is specifically set to a certain class.

Later, Josh edited his post, essentially using the exact same method that I did when I initially posted my answer.

Another user now, whose answer was insufficient, is [directing the OP to Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661020/how-to-target-html-element-from-a-specific-class-of-a-body-element#comment-10763280).

I also gave another method to do exactly what the OP asked, but still no dice. My answer is being completely ignored.

It's not that I'm upset about it, but it's not exactly fair, especially when the user whose answer is getting the attention used the same method I did *after* I posted my answer.

My first instinct is to leave it alone, but I'm sure we've all been through this and we all have the urge to say something. Is my first instinct the right one?

Comment: By doing nothing. Just find another question to answer.

Comment: @Scrooge: I knew that would be the answer. :P

Comment: (*Slightly* related, but maybe you feel the need to support it: [Add an indication that a post has been edited in the 5 minutes grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39635/add-an-indication-that-a-post-has-been-edited-in-the-5-minutes-grace-period) and [Change the way edits in the grace period work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40257/change-the-way-edits-in-the-grace-period-work).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leave it alone, or try to make it more "attractive" by editing it.

As to why your answer was ignored: I think it's because it doesn't look verbose enough at the first glance. It seems to contain only code. Of course, it is explained perfectly by great comments *inside the code* - it's a perfectly good answer. But at a quick glance, it looks like  a "code only" answer, and from experience, I can say that *something* about them makes most people ignore them unless the code is something really, really obvious triggering an "Ah!" in the audience. It's a split second decision that I can't really explain, but slightly more verbose answers really tend to fare better.

Maybe it's because a bit of verbosity ("If your x is version y, you can do this...") resembles a real human face-to-face conversation more than a few lines of code? I don't know.

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing; +1. Sometimes it may be unfair, but answers that appear to be 'code only' don't entice me to read them as much as questions with a balance of code and text.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: [I would know](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). :P (And, funny enough, you answered that question).